# Will removing my keyword from breadcrumb title to simplify UI hurt page SEO?

Tags: seo, keywords, breadcrumbs

Working on the UI of a new site and I would like to simplify some breadcrumb titles so they do not take up as much space. They will still communicate the same message to user.

**See example below:**

- Before:  *Home > **Widget** Dealers > Tennessee > Nashville*
- After:  *Home > Dealers > Tennessee > Nashville*

The page title and/or menu item would still be "Widget Dealers". So my question is, if I remove the keyword "Widget" only from the breadcrumb could that have a poor impact on page optimization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not generally, no. Breadcrumbs are helpful for SERPs but not necessarily recognized as content.

Things have changed. In the early days of breadcrumbs, the text was indexed as content, however, I do not think that is the case anymore now that Google has gotten smarter about mark-up. Either way, it is just one simple word that could be made up for easily. Keywords found in breadcrumbs never enjoyed special weighting. If you find there seems to be a difference, you can simply re-add the keyword into the upper portion of content rather than the breadcrumb and all will be sunshine and roses again. Again, I do not think that breadcrumbs are indexed as content anymore.

Comment: @the-coopersmith Thanks! I try. I am semi-retired and do not follow all of the CMS/blog stuff, but I do know SEO fairly well and I am always here to help. I do security research too and so I have some home-grown tools that can help from time to time if you see funny things in your log file. I do not know specific attacks always, but more about where attacks come from and why.

Comment: Duly noted for future help! Thanks for you insight and quick response.